# Color a part of Text in drop down list

Tags: c#

Is there any way through which i can color a part of text in Drop down list.
I am filling by Drop down list with .
Sumthing like- (102) Just an example. and so on.
I want (102) to be displayed in one color(RED) and resty of the string in default Black COlor.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You look some think like this.

```
foreach (ListItem item in DropDownList.Items)
{

 string s1 = "102";
 string s2 = item.Text;

 if(s2.Contains(s1))
 {
  item.Attributes.Add("style", "color:red");
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I fetching count of value form DB and storing in a variable and then filling the dropdownlist like cbxValuesList.Items.Add("(" + EventCount.ToString()+ ")" + " " + dataRow[0].ToString().Trim());  
 How can i compare with the value of variable. Will it work for a part of text in a single row of DropdownList.

Comment: cbxValuesList.Items.Add("(" + EventCount.ToString()+ ")" + " " + dataRow[0].ToString().Trim()); foreach (ListItem item in cbxValuesList.Items) { string s1 = EventCount.ToString(); string s2 = item.Text; if (s2.Contains(s1)) { item.Attributes.Add("style", "color: red"); }

Comment: 1.Getting error
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'.
FOR  foreach (ListItem item in cbxValuesList.Items) 
2.  if (s2.Contains(s1))
       {
           item.Attributes.Add("style", "color: red");
       }
Evry row will contain EventCount value.
How its will color jst count value.
(1024) Time out occured.
(1024) should be RED. 
TIme out occured in DEFAULT BLACK.